# UWP / C# - How to tell what type of ViewModel is currently being displayed

Tags: c#, mvvm, uwp

What I need is a way to programmatically find which ViewModel (in MVVM) corresponds to what is currently being displayed on the app.

I have a ViewModel that contains a comm handler method.  This comm handler is called from an external thread.  When this happens, I need to do one of two things: if the view corresponding to the VM is on the screen, I need to parse and display the message contents to the screen.  If the view corresponding to the VM is not on the screen, I need to store the message for later.

For example, if I have a DisplayPage.xaml and a DisplayPageViewModel.cs, and the app is currently displaying the contents of DisplayPage, I would like something similar to the code below to reach the specific task.

```
if (<code to find VM type here> == typeof(DisplayPageViewModel)){
    //do viewmodel specific task
}
```

However, if the app was currently displaying MainPage.xaml, I do not want the code to run.

Comment: Use the "is" keyword to check the type of the DataContext.  If DataContext is DisplayPageViewModel {} else if (DataContext is .... ) {}

Comment: DataContext is usually a View field.  Is there a way to get the current View that is being shown to the user?  As I said below in a comment, there is no DataContext where this code snippet is being run.

Comment: where is the code snippet running?

Comment: It's in an event handler within said ViewModel.  It's called by an external messaging thread, which is the issue.  I need to figure out if, when the method is called, the viewmodel is "current" or on-screen.

Comment: This is pretty bad.  You should tell us in an [edit] what you're attempting to accomplish and why.  That way we can tell you what you need to do, rather than help you accomplish this wrongheaded goal.

Comment: @Will  - try that ^^

Comment: Aaaah, okay.  Why not just always parse and place the message on a public property of the view model?  When the user switches back to that view, the message gets displayed automatically.

Comment: I've tried to do that in the past and I got a threading / marshaling error.  I'm currently looking into solutions for that other than doing all parsing on the GUI thread.

Comment: I'd suggest reviewing what MVVM is, what each layer is and why this architecture exists.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/mvvm/ If you are trying to figure out what view is on the screen from the view model then you are breaking the pattern.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `is` keyword to check type. You can use the `DataContext` property to, well, get the DataContext :-)

```
public class ViewModelOne{

}

public class ViewModelTwo{

}


public class MasterClass : Control{

    public void CheckViewModel(){
         if(this.DataContext is ViewModelOne){

         }
         else if(this.DataContext is ViewModelTwo){

         }
    }

}
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions / guides on where this code should be placed?  I tried to put it in my event handler (inside of DisplayPageViewModel, but called from an external thread), and it said there is no DataContext.

Comment: @Sonicarrow without seeing your entire application I can't tell you where to put code.... I can tell you without question this is the way though lol

Comment: I found a reference to DataContext in one of my .xaml.cs files, so that's what I was looking for in the previous comment.  

Your answer helps when a view needs to find its viewmodel, but my situation is I need an arbitrary piece of code in the app to find which view is currently on the screen.  Once I find the view, then I can use the datacontext to find the viewmodel  (or just compare based on the view itself).

Comment: The whole point of MVVM is that the ViewModel has no idea, nor does it care what View is attached to it. If you need to know what view is on the screen then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: @AnthonyRussell I mostly agree with your statement, yet sometimes it *might* be entirely necessary for the View to know about the ViewModel in some circumstances.

Comment: If your view knows about the view model it's using it's not a crime. However if your view model knows the view then you've broken the pattern and it's not mvvm. There's no exceptions. If you need to interact with the UI from the view model then you use interactivity requests.